# Building rubygem: many dependencies - bad practice?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Let's say I have a gem with over 7 runtime dependencies, and each of these dependencies have their own dependencies. One of the cons I see is that it'll increase the install time.

Is it bad practice to have many dependencies for a gem?

Comment: Consider registering your project with https://gemnasium.com to help track problem dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the dependancies are (some gems are small, some are big), but as long as it's not 7 fairly large ones, it's probably ok.

That being said, you should consider if all of the dependancies you're including are necessary- if they are, then don't worry about it.